How can I use encryption on a TMyQuery's parameters?
I use MyDAC's built-in encryption (ie MyTable.Encryption.Encryptor). This works fine for tables, and for SELECT queries, but not for INSERT queries. Is there a way of telling MyDAC to encrypt TMyQuery's parameters (from the 'ParamByName' function) or am I stuck here ?
Thanks.
